# WebLogic: Adding JMS resources to fresh domain

Tags: weblogic, jms

I am writing integration tests for a software product which require WebLogic 12.1.3 and WebLogic 12.2.1 to be started with a fresh domain.

Currently I do something like this to start WebLogic with a fresh domain:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/domain && \
cd /tmp/domain && \
/opt/jdk1.8.0_72/bin/java -cp /wls/server/lib/weblogic.jar \
  -Dweblogic.ListenPort=7001 \
  -Dweblogic.management.GenerateDefaultConfig=true \
  -Dweblogic.management.username=admin \
  -Dweblogic.management.password=testpass! \
  weblogic.Server
```

Now I need to create JMS resources (similar to the existing samples) which I have created an XML file for.
What do I have to do so the XML file is used to crate the JMS resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First configure the JMS servers using console or update the below snippet in the `config.xml`. (Take the backup of `config.xml` before any changes.)

```
<jms-server>
    <name>JMSserver1</name>
    <target>managed1 (migratable)</target>
    <persistent-store>Filestore1</persistent-store>
  </jms-server>
  <jms-server>
    <name>JMSserver2</name>
    <target>managed2 (migratable)</target>
    <persistent-store>Filestore2</persistent-store>
  </jms-server>
```

Now if you place the XML files under `/$Domain_home/config/jms` and restart the managed servers, it has to pick the JMS configuration. Let me know if any assistance is required.